# spring boot cannot connect to rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a RabbitMQ server like this
[image]

When I try to connect to this server via Spring Boot amqp, I see `com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.`

My configs are this one

```
# Message
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://127.0.0.1:5672
spring.activemq.user=test
spring.activemq.password=test
```

Yes, the user test can access Virtual Hosts on / and yes, I can login with test/test on RabbitMQ GUI

**EDIT**

Looking at the rabbitmq logs, I saw this

```
{handshake_error,starting,0,
             {amqp_error,access_refused,
                         "PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials",
                         'connection.start_ok'}}
```

seems like Spring is ignoring my configs and trying to connect with `guest`

Comment: In spring config you have `activemq.user=test` but you connects to rabbitmq, not activemq and rabbitmq logs shows that you connect under `guest` username

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Properties includes specific settings for RabbitMQ. Try replacing your ActiveMQ config with below.

Example:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host = 127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
spring.rabbitmq.username = guest
spring.rabbitmq.password = guest
```

Answer (score 6):

src/main/resources/application.yml

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    username: guest
    password: guest
    host: rabbitmq
    port: 5672
    virtual-host: someVirtualHost
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your rabbitMQ configuration in spring boot properties  :

```
spring.rabbitmq.host = 127.0.0.1
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
spring.rabbitmq.username = guest
spring.rabbitmq.password = guest
```

Answer (score 0):

Using default setting up with springboot is good but if we want to add external rabbit instance to spring container then we should follow as below

application.yml

```
rabbitmq:
  host: 'hostname'
  vhost: 'vhostname'
  user: 'userName'
  password: 'passwd'
  port: 5672
```

Config class

```
        @Configuration
    public class RabbitConfig {

        @Value("${rabbitmq.host}")
        private String host;
        @Value("${rabbitmq.vhost}")
        private String vhost;
        @Value("${rabbitmq.user}")
        private String user;
        @Value("${rabbitmq.password}")
        private String password;
        @Value("${rabbitmq.port}")
        private int port;

        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
            CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
            System.out.println("rmqhost is " + host);
            factory.setHost(host);
            factory.setVirtualHost(vhost);
            factory.setUsername(user);
            factory.setPassword(password);
            factory.setPort(port);
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
            return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        }

    }
```

and we can create Bean for either rabbitmqtemplate or rabbitmqListener